# status 500 from JIRA 7.2 server when authenticating from hybrid mobile app using REST API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am getting a status 500 code form JIRA server when trying to authenticate using the JIRA REST API. JIRA Server version 7.2 the same app was working fine in JIRA Server version < 7. The app is n android app developed using apache cordova

When I used chrome debugger found the following as the request being sent(actual username/password removed)

> curl https://www.wso2.org/jira/rest/auth/1/session" -H "Origin:
>   file://" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "X-Requested-With:
>   com.ionicframework.wso2support797980" -H "Accept-Language:
>   en-GB,en-US;q=0.8" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1;
>   SM-G930F Build/MMB29K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Version/4.0 Chrome/53.0.2785.124 Mobile Safari/537.36" -H
>   "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json,
>   text/plain, */*" -H "X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:
>   e75994c2-e8c7-4148-a73b-b8c8abbd0601" -H "Cookie:
>   atlassian.xsrf.token=A6BL-PURG-37QO-G55K|1de97dad4ce95a2ee8acf90e2afb63ce32d703fe|lout"
>   -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data-binary "{""username"":""xxxxxxxxx"",""password"":""xxxxxxxxx""}"
>   --compressed

Error

> {"message":"Expected authority at index 7: file://","status-code":500,"stack-trace":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected authority at index 7: file://\n\tat java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)\n\tat com.atlassian.applinks.cors.auth.DefaultCorsService.getApplicationLinksByOrigin(DefaultCorsService.java:50)\n\tat com.atlassian.applinks.cors.auth.AppLinksCorsDefaults.allowsOrigin(AppLinksCorsDefaults.java:39)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.security.jersey.XsrfResourceFilter$1.apply(XsrfResourceFilter.java:227)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.security.jersey.XsrfResourceFilter$1.apply(XsrfResourceFilter.java:225)\n\tat com.google.common.collect.Iterators.indexOf(Iterators.java:778)\n\tat com.google.common.collect.Iterators.any(Iterators.java:684)\n\tat com.google.common.collect.Iterables.any(Iterables.java:623)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.security.jersey.XsrfResourceFilter.isAllowedViaCors(XsrfResourceFilter.java:225)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.security.jersey.XsrfResourceFilter.passesAdditionalBrowserChecks(XsrfResourceFilter.java:166)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.security.jersey.OriginBasedXsrfResourceFilter.filter(OriginBasedXsrfResourceFilter.java:19)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:281)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter$JerseyOsgiServletContainer.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:154)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:829)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:68)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:70)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.doFilterInternal(RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.java:22)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.doFilter(RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.java:34)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.mywork.client.filter.ServingRequestsFilter.doFilter(ServingRequestsFilter.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.request.RedirectInterceptingFilter.doFilter(RedirectInterceptingFilter.java:21)\n\tat com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.java:32)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.java:55)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.java:79)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.java:51)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.labs.botkiller.BotKillerFilter.doFilter(BotKillerFilter.java:36)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:70)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:58)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.executeRequest(AccessLogFilter.java:92)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.security.xsrf.XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.doFilter(XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.java:49)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.pagebuilder.PageBuilderFilter.doFilter(PageBuilderFilter.java:81)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.CommittedResponseHtmlErrorRecoveryFilter.doFilter(CommittedResponseHtmlErrorRecoveryFilter.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:70)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:58)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MauEventFilter.doFilter(MauEventFilter.java:49)\n\tat com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(JiraSecurityFilter.java:76)\n\tat com.atlassian.seraph.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:242)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.doFilter(JiraSecurityFilter.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:103)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:148)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLoginFilter.doFilter(JiraLoginFilter.java:82)\n\tat com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:79)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestSeraphFilter.doFilter(RestSeraphFilter.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.rest.auth.JiraRestSeraphAuthFilter.doFilter(JiraRestSeraphAuthFilter.java:41)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:70)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:58)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.johnson.filters.AbstractJohnsonFilter.doFilter(AbstractJohnsonFilter.java:59)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.johnson.JiraJohnson503Filter.doFilter(JiraJohnson503Filter.java:24)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)\n\tat org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)\n\tat org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)\n\tat org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.doFilter(CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.java:30)\n\tat com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.JiraAnalyticsFilter.doFilter(JiraAnalyticsFilter.java:42)\n\tat com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:39)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.request.RedirectInterceptingFilter.doFilter(RedirectInterceptingFilter.java:21)\n\tat com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.LocationCleanerFilter.doFilter(LocationCleanerFilter.java:36)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)\n\tat com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:70)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:58)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.core.filters.cache.AbstractCachingFilter.doFilter(AbstractCachingFilter.java:31)\n\tat com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.core.filters.encoding.AbstractEncodingFilter.doFilter(AbstractEncodingFilter.java:39)\n\tat com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.PathMatchingEncodingFilter.doFilter(PathMatchingEncodingFilter.java:39)\n\tat com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.startup.JiraStartupChecklistFilter.doFilter(JiraStartupChecklistFilter.java:62)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MultipartBoundaryCheckFilter.doFilter(MultipartBoundaryCheckFilter.java:36)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.MetricsCollectorFilter.doFilter(MetricsCollectorFilter.java:25)\n\tat com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:74)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraFirstFilter.doFilter(JiraFirstFilter.java:59)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilterInternal(GzipFilter.java:121)\n\tat com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:92)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.gzip.JiraGzipFilter.doFilter(JiraGzipFilter.java:45)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.InstantUpgradeHoldingFilter.doFilter(InstantUpgradeHoldingFilter.java:99)\n\tat com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\nCaused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected authority at index 7: file://\n\tat java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)\n\tat java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2854)\n\tat java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3102)\n\tat java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)\n\tat java.net.URI.(URI.java:588)\n\tat java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850)\n\t... 235 more\n"}

What might be causing this issue?

Thank You

Comment: This "{""username"":""xxxxxxxxx"",""password"":""xxxxxxxxx""}" doesn't look right. I think you're trying to escape quotes by quoting twice.  Instead try either '{"username":"xxxxxxx","password":"xxxxxxx"}' or try "{\"username\":\"xxxxxx\" ... }"  (i.e. backslash to escape)

Comment: i dont think that is the problem i copied the CURL directly from chrome dev tools. I found that the problem is only in POST requests. Any guidance is much appreciated.

[similar problem](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/32520476/mobile-hybrid-application-throwing-500-error-on-all-posts-after-update-to-jira-7)

Comment: found that the error is in the contents of the "User Agent" header

Comment: @jamesorc I couldn't find a proper solution had to create a small server-side app to send the request through it. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To this problem I am not sure how Attlasian is addressing this, but here is a detailed work-around that can be done till there is any fix coming soon.

Hope this helps other's

Note: Make sure to install npm (node any version greater than 4)

1. Clone the following repository 
   https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere.git
2. Enter the directory cors-anywhere once cloned successfully & run `npm install`
3. Inside the directory of cors-anywhere edit the Server.js file, find the following line  `requireHeader: ['origin', 'x-requested-with'],`and remove or comment it.
4. Then run the following `node server.js`
5. By default the server will be listening at `localhost:8080` then you can bypass the API calls via this server like this `localhost:8080/https://<your-JIRA-Server>/rest/api/latest/<path-to-api>` (This would work for any POST, GET, PUT, DELETE calls)

By this process it will resolve the CORS issue with JIRA server & API calls will be successful from your ionic application once you build and release app for Android/IOS along with this it would work with the webApp as well.